# Django path not matching with urlpatterns in urls.py

Tags: python, django

Guys I am not a web developer, I have been learning django for a couple of hours now for my father's small business website and  I am hitting a silly  error for hours now.[image]

the name of the project is mysite and mysite urls.py looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("index.urls")),
    path("about/", include("about_page.urls")),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")), 
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite's settings.py also includes the correct AppConfig for the app. about_page included.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'index.apps.IndexConfig',
    'about_page.apps.AboutPageConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

about_page's views.py is attached_below

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader 
from django.http import Http404


# Create your views here.
    # return HttpResponse("website under construction !!!")
def about_func(request):
    template = loader.get_template("about/about_page.html")
    context = {
        "about":"about_us",
        }
     
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

about_page's urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path 

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("about/", views.about_func, name="about_page"),
]
```

polls and index apps have exact same pattern, i simply don't know why i cannot display about page.

Comment: In addition to the answers other people left, it looks like you're reinventing the wheel in your view. If you import `render` from `django.shortcuts`, you can do this instead: `return render(request, "about/about_page.html", context)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you defined root url in mysite's urls.py to

```py
path("about/", include("about_page.urls")),
```

so at this point all urls that you are including(so all urls in about_page urls.py file) will go like `{base_url}/about/{url defined in about_page.urls`

Then you define in about_page urls:

```py
path("about/", views.about_func, name="about_page"),
```

So now your url to about_func is
`{base_url}/about/about/`

What you probably want to do is left with empty string instead of **"about/"** in about_page urls.py

```py
path("", views.about_func, name="about_page"),
```

or even directly import view to app.urls and root from there

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `about` in your about_page's urls.py as you have already included it in your project's root urls.py

**about_page.urls.py**:

```
path("", views.about_func, name="about_page")
```